# TypeError: react_1.forwardRef is not a function

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have developed a website using react js and I have used following libraries for that.

```
"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
"date-fns": "^2.14.0",
"flatlist-react": "^1.4.2",
"keycloak-js": "^10.0.0",
"moment": "^2.18.1",
"react": "^16.1.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
"react-date-range": "^1.0.3"
```

It was working all fine, but it's just started giving me an error and I can't figure out what's wrong.

This is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

This is the code of the flatlist in my project.

```
<FlatList
    list={this.props.list}
    renderItem={this.props.renderItem}
    renderWhenEmpty={this.props.renderWhenEmpty}
    hasMoreItems={this.props.hasMoreItems}
    loadMoreItems={this.props.loadMoreItems}
/>
```

But as it seems, this is not a problem in my code. Please guide me. What should I do?

If any more clarification is needed, let me know.

Comment: Can you try import `{ forwardRef } from 'react'` at the top with your imports to see if it helps anything?

Comment: No sir that didn't work.